# JQuery: Toggle issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My intentions are to display a `slidediv` on a link to show and hide, but when I implement the `slidediv` in another form, or `<div>` element, the tooltip div doesn't work.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.showhide').click(function() {
        $(".slidediv").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.slidediv{
    width: 30%;
    padding:20px;
    background:#EB5E00;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #FFF;
}
</style>
```

PHP and HTML:

```
echo '<a href=# alt=Image Tooltip rel=tooltip content="<div class=td2><div id=imagcon><img src=img/1.jpg class=tooltip-image/></div><div id=con>'.$friendList['BedRooms'].' bhk </div><div id=con>'.$friendList['property_type'].'</div><div id=con>Area:'.$friendList['CoveredArea'].'</div><div id=con> '.$friendList['Type_cust'].' :'.$friendList['FirstName'].' '.$friendList['LastName'].' </div> <div id=con> 
<a href=# > View All Details </a> 
  </div>
<br/>
  <div id=con> <a href=# class=showhide>';
 echo " <img src='Dealer/images/email_send.png' style='width:22px;height:22px' />";  
 echo ' Contact Advertiser </a>   </div>';
 echo "<div class='slidediv'>
<div id='lgndiv' class='div-0-ryh' >
<div class='div-1-ryh'>
<form  method='post' onsubmit='' action='' target='_blank' class='form-3-ryh'>
<div class='div-4-ryh '>
<table cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='table-5-ryh'>
        <colgroup>
        </colgroup>
            <tbody class='table-5-ryh'>
            <tr class='tr-8-ryh'>
                <td class='td-9-ryh'>
                    <div class='div-10-ryh'>
                        <span class='span-11-ryh'>Your Name:</span>
                            <input name='name' valtype='name' required='true' class='input-12-ryh' style='background-color:#FFFFFF'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='div-10-ryh'>
                        <span class='span-14-ryh'>Email:</span>
                            <input name='email' valtype='email' required='true' class='input-15-ryh' style='background-color:#FFFFFF'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='div-16-ryh'>
                        <span class='span-17-ryh'>Phone:</span>
                            <input name='phone' required='true' maxlength='13' valtype='phmob' class='input-18-ryh' style='background-color:#FFFFFF'>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='tr-19-ryh'>
                  <td colspan='2' class='td-20-ryh'>
                    <span id='text5'>This is for verification purpose and will be asked only once.</span>
                  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='tr-22-ryh'>
                <td>
                    <span id='text5'>By clicking this you agree to </span><a target='_blank' href='/load/Company/termsconditions' class='a-25-ryh'>Terms and conditions.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2' class='td-27-ryh'>
                <div id='submit_ViewPhnoD11255903' class='div-28-ryh'>
                    <span id='savedetail_ViewPhno_D11255903'>
                    <input type='' value=''  class='input-30-ryh'>
                    </span>
                    <span class='span-31-ryh'>
                        <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='jsui.hideCurLyr();pg.closeModalLayer(); return false;' class='a-25-ryh'>Cancel</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</form>
<div class='div-52-ryh'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried adding a `alert()` or a `console.log()` inside the click event to see if it is triggered?

Comment: also you have this in your code `<a href=# class=showhide>` try adding `'` to the class name.

Comment: Is this intended: `echo '<a href=# alt=Image Tooltip rel=tooltip content="<div c...` It would appear that there is html inside your content attribute's value, which may be generating invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JavaScript needs to be added to the page after this HTML is echoed.  Have you done that?

Also, it looks like there is some invalid HTML being returned.  Those errors shouldn't affect the JavaScript, however.

```
$bedrooms     = $friendList['BedRooms'];
$propertyType = $friendList['property_type']
$coveredArea  = $friendList['CoveredArea'];
$custType     = $friendList['Type_cust'];
$fullName     = $friendList['FirstName'].' '.$friendList['LastName'];

// It would appear that this html is broken
// Try fixing this first line and see if that resolve the issue
echo '<a href="#" alt="Image Tooltip" rel="tooltip" content=""></a>';
echo '<div class="td2">';
    echo '<div id="imagcon">';
        echo '<img src="img/1.jpg" class="tooltip-image" />';
    echo '</div>';

    // As a matter of technicality, don't use the same ID more than once
    echo '<div id="con">'.$bedrooms.' bhk </div>';
    echo '<div id="con">'.$propertyType.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="con">Area:'.$coveredArea.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="con"> '.$custType.' :'.$fullNName.' </div>';
    echo '<div id="con"><a href="#"> View All Details </a></div>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<div id="con">';
        echo '<a href="#" class="showhide">';
            echo '<img src="Dealer/images/email_send.png" style="width:22px;height:22px" /> Contact Advertiser ';
        echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="slidediv">';
        echo '<div id="lgndiv" class="div-0-ryh">';
            echo '<div class="div-1-ryh">';
                echo '<form method="post" onsubmit="" action="" target="_blank" class="form-3-ryh">';
                    echo '<div class="div-4-ryh">';
                        echo '<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table-5-ryh">';
                            echo '<colgroup></colgroup>';
                            echo '<tbody class="table-5-ryh">';
                            echo '... rest of the form ...';
                            echo '</tbody>';
                        echo '</table>';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</form>';
                echo '<div class="div-52-ryh"></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

if your JavaScript loads or is rendered AFTER this html is echoed, then I suggest you also add it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// This should be equivalent to document.ready()
$(function() {
    // See if your element exists or not
    if($('.showhide').length){
        $('.showhide').click(function() {
            $(".slidediv").slideToggle();
            return false;
        });
    } else {
        // If you have a console in your browser (not everyone does)
        // and calling console.log() may generate errors on older IEs
        if(window.console){
            console.log('.showhide was not found');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```